# How to add animation to recycler view onclick function?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I want to add animation to recycle view with any kind of `onclick()`
so that when i click on the item at that position will flip and the next activity will then be visible.

on click of the item, it should flip and the next activity has to be displayed

Comment: Hi, please consider sharing code, Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for full solutions ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sagar Welcome to StackOverflow! For your kind information, as a member of the community, I Should remind you that this community is for getting help in the errors that you get in you code. No one is that free to write the whole code for you. But you may represent your code and we may help you in that. Hope you understand

Comment: You can have a good reference from this site.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: sorry for the mistake but the thing is i dont have any error in my code i just wanted to add animation to the recycleview items onclick event

Answer (score 0):

I am getting your point. add below line in your item layout parent and you will get a clickable animation.

```
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: not the exact thing that i wanted but still thank u for helping

Comment: @sagardeshmukh could you please share the refrence what exactly you want to do

Comment: sure i have recycleview which consist of cardview elemtents what i want is when i click on one of the item in recycleview it shout have to show flip animation and after that the next activity should be visible